# Understanding Doctrine 2 ORM and how it can and should work with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, orm, doctrine-orm

I would like to integrate Doctrine 2 ORM into WordPress for use in the plugins I'm developing. There is currently a plugin that offers [Doctrine 1.2.3 ORM support in WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/doctrine/), but not v2.

The biggest problem I'm having is that I don't understand how Doctrine 2 ORM interacts with my code; specifically, what their [configuration code](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/configuration.html) provides me with and where I should go from here:

```
// 3.1.1
require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php';
$lib = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/lib';
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::registerAutoloadDirectory($lib);

// 3.1.2
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;

if($applicationMode == "development") {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
} else {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
}

$config = new Configuration;
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver('/path/to/lib/MyProject/Entities');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setProxyDir('/path/to/myproject/lib/MyProject/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('MyProject\Proxies');

if ($applicationMode == "development") {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
} else {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
}

$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => 'database.sqlite'
);

$em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

I had continued reading through sections of the documentation up to section 8 and have some understanding. My questions are:

1. Is this configuration enough to allow me to work with Doctrine 2 ORM in my plugins?
2. Are there any other key steps I'm missing before working with Doctrine 2 ORM? The WordPress plugin seems to automatically generate all of the appropriate classes from the database. I read the documentation a few times, but I feel like I'm missing some big step... or maybe Doctrine 2 ORM is just that much different?
3. Is the EntityManager some global variable that I can use throughout my entities?
4. I assume I have to link everything together, `@Entity` in a file is not enough for Doctrine to know where the entity is. Is there somewhere in the documentation that defines this?

If anyone can provide a quick rundown of how it all works together: configuration, entities, etc. Or provide any clear cut tutorials that may already be out there, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There are 2 things I am unclear of. #1 why would anyone do this other than a challenge? It just makes a heavy system that a ton heavier with no real positive outcome. #2 If you don't understand Doctrine, why would you use it in plugins you need to maintain? The whole idea is crazy. Use the WordPress API provided.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you shouldn't use Doctrine2 with WP

1. Doctrine 2 is more appropriate solution for site with huge business logic and I believe you don't use WP for this purposes
2. Doctrine 2 has huge code base (~11MB) which add overhead for classloading and processing of requests
3. Doctrine 2 use a lot of memory with default hydration mode (object)
4. Building custom sql is much harder with Doctrine.